# python elasticsarch integration

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have to update a field in `elasticsearch` using `python`. `Elasticsearch` is `password enabled` '-u' I can use.

---

Example:

Field to update in `Elasticsearch` is `'reservestatus'` should be updated from queried to open
If `search_timestamp-current_timestamp>10 mins` ( *`search_timestamp`* is a field which I am adding in `elasticsearch`).

I am new to this, any leads would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can start reading about the [official python client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html) and reading its [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you need to do it two steps: first, get all the documents you want to update and then update them.

To get the documents, use the search function. Try this:

```py
body= {
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "search_timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-10m"
      }
    }
  }
}

res = client.search(index="YourIndexName", body=body)
```

Then iterate over the results, get the ID of each document and update:

```py
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
  doc_id = doc._id
  body = {
    "doc" : {
      "reservestatus": "open"
    }
  }
  client.update(index="YourIndexName", id=doc_id, body=body)
```

If you want to improve performance, you can use the [bulk](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk) api.